# rails device not keeping GET params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one running rails app with device gem. I want pass some urls with params (in url) in email. when user click on it and if user is logged in everything works (ULR is like myhost.com/myaction?my_var=xx) 
but if user is not logged in it redirects to sign in path. after giving credentials it lost my_var value and app breaks. (yes it goes to my action)

for now I am redirecting user to his dashboard with error msg but anyone have good solution?

Comment: You can validate and save your params to user session and after logging in you can use them for things you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to overwrite the default Devise behavior after a successful authentication by defining the after_sign_in_path_for method in your ApplicationController:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:stored_path] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
```

In this example Devise will check whether the session[:stored_path] is set, if not it will try to load the stored_location_for(resource) path and as a fail save it will eventually redirect_to the root_path.

In this case you'll need to set the session[:stored_path] upon redirect when the current_user isn't logged in.